# my high efficiency furnace shuts off during sub-zero weather

Tags: furnace

My high efficiency furnace shuts off only during sub zero weather. I've ruled out intake and exhaust clogging, and water pump problems. Do you have any other ideas about what could be causing this problem? As soon as the outside temp rises, the furnace resumes normal function.

Comment: Most furnaces tell you using diagnostic codes what is going on. Often, there is a small light behind the front cover somewhere that blink in certain combinations, and a label on the back of the cover to decode the blinking codes. Does yours indicate anything there?

Comment: Is it gas or electric?

Comment: I will not know now that the temp has risen. until it gets very cold again. it is a gas unit.

Comment: I have not seen a high efficiency gas furnace fail from outside temps. I would checking to make sure the filters are clean and verify the pressure / flow switches are working.

Comment: it may have something to do with the outside air intake .... do you leave any windows open when the temperature outside rises and close them when it gets cold?

Comment: I have a similar issue with my older HE furnace, being almost 30 years old, it has no diagnostic codes. Mine does the same thing, outside temps below freezing and it fails to work properly without manually disconnecting power for a few minutes then applying power. I have spent 5 years trying to figure it out. I have replaced numerous parts. But one part that I have questioned the most is the pilot system. Check your burner box and the pilot...is it rusty inside? You might be getting water in the burner box and rusting the contacts on the pilot.